# Jquery autocomplete is not autocompleting

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have set up a jquery autocomplete using a php file to get my data from a database and parse it to json.  The problem is when I start typing the name of the employee I am getting the entire list of names not just the employee. Here is my code below.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("#employee").autocomplete({
        source:"allemployeesjson.php",
        minLength:1
    });
   });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <label for="employee">Employee:</label>
    <input id="employee" />
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you show contents of allemployeesjson.php? Depends how you are returning the data.

Comment: You need to filter in your PHP file, the Autocomplete plugin won't do that if you call an external datasource. Please read the [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source). If that is still unclear, please edit your post and show us your PHP files content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out what the issue was.  The original php file was the below file. 
I had not put a get in it for the data to update.

```
<?php
session_save_path("../itshear");
session_start();
include('../common.php');
$appquery = "select SSN,cast(rtrim(Lastn)+', '+rtrim(Firstn) as varchar(60))  employee from datatable where mchEmploy = '1' and Persontypeid = '2' order by employee";
$emplist=sqlsrv_query($link,$appquery,array(),array( "Scrollable" => 'static' )) or die('Cannot get employee list');
unset($_SESSION['employees']); 
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($emplist,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $_SESSION['employees'][]=array('value'=>$row['employee'],'ssn'=>$row['SSN']);
    }
 $_SESSION['json']['employees']= json_encode($_SESSION['employees']);
 echo $_SESSION['json']['employees'];
?>
```

This is the changed file and it worked fine.

```
<?php
session_save_path("../itshear");
session_start();
include('../common.php');
$q = $_GET['term'];
if(!$q){return;}
$appquery = "select Mchnum,SSN,cast(rtrim(Lastn)+', '+rtrim(Firstn) as varchar(60))  employee from datatable where mchEmploy = '1' and Persontypeid = '2' and Lastn like '".$q."%' order by employee";
$emplist=sqlsrv_query($link,$appquery,array(),array( "Scrollable" => 'static' )) or die('Cannot get employee list');
unset($_SESSION['employees']); 
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($emplist,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $_SESSION['employees'][]=array('value'=>$row['employee'],'ssn'=>$row['SSN']);
    }
 $_SESSION['json']['employees']= json_encode($_SESSION['employees']);
 echo $_SESSION['json']['employees'];
?>
```